# My responsive navbar is not responsive on mobile devices(overflow problem?)

Tags: html, css, layout

So i'm trying to build a responsive nav bar for a website, on Desktops it works great, however on mobile devices, no amount of me working with the overflow: hidden; will actually make the overflow go away.

When I originally started looking into this problem, I found a couple forums that said sometimes you need to assign "overflow: hidden;" to a more specific part of the html, so I tried that, but with no avail. My overflow is still all out in the open on mobile devices.

```
.mobile{
      display: none;
      cursor: pointer;
      overflow-x: hidden
  }

  .mobile div{
    width: 25px;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #2d3436;
    margin: 5px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
  }

  @media screen and(max-width:1024px){
      .main-nav{
          width: 60%;
      }
  }

  @media screen and (max-width:786px){
      body{
          overflow: hidden;
      }
      .main-nav{
          position: absolute;
          right: 0px;
          height: 92vh;
          top: 8vh; 
          background-color: white;
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;
          align-items: center;
          justify-content: center;
          width: 100%;
          transform: translateX(100%);
          transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
        }
        .main-nav li {
            opacity: 0;
        }
        .mobile{
            display: block;
        }
    }
```

To my knowledge(which granted isn't much) this should be a responsive navbar that has no overflow on mobile devices, I do have a link to the test website as well if you'd like to see it in action. I'm probably just missing something small, but I'm beat, I've been looking into this for hours. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please include your HTML and any other code relevant to reproducing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this in the head tag of your HTML

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
```

Comment: Disabling zoom is very user-unfriendly. I do not recommend it. It's best to just use this: `<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, width=device-width">`